# Why does Posfix “limits” me to use only one domain under “internet-site”?

Tags: configuration, email, postfix

When I install Postfix as a mail server to transfer emails from my [Content Management System's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) contact-forms, into my Gmail account, I choose the option **internet-site**. After I choose that option Postfix asks me to insert the domain of my site.

But what I have 2 or more sites instead just one? What domain should I insert then?

I don't assume the creators of Postfix expect users to enter a long list of domains separated by commas.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of choices is not a standard Postfix feature; it's probably the result of the package management system of your Linux distribution. Perhaps Ubuntu, or some other Debian-related distribution?

If I'm correct, you should treat the option dialog as an "easy first installation wizard" only. For a non-trivial configuration, the "training wheels" will have to come off: you'd use the `postconf` command to further adjust the configuration, or perhaps stop Postfix and then replace the default configuration files with your own customized ones.

Comment: Indeed I use Ubuntu 16.04. In the last passage, did you mean to install it with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`?

Comment: Please reply so if yes, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: This.  And a good howto for configuring postfix for multiple domains and virutal users and such is https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

Comment: I meant that the package manager's questions can't possibly cover all the configurability that an enterprise-grade MTA like Postfix has. If it can provide a default configuration that allows basic email connectivity for your primary site, that's nice; but that's just for getting started. If you're automating a mail server set-up with something like SaltStack or Ansible, installing the Postfix package using a non-interactive debconf frontend and then wholesale replacing the default configuration with a pre-customized one might be a good choice.